# Add/remove methods from a callback list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, object-literal

I have an object that stores all instances of UI widgets on my page and some of them have callbacks passed as options when the widget is created.

```
Page.menu = Widget.sidePanel({
  trigger: "#menu-toggler",
  panel: "#menu-panel",
  onOpen: function(){
    Page.otherPanel.close();
    Page.yetAnother.close();
  }
}),
```

After creation, the "onOpen" option is stored/accessible at "Page.menu.onOpen" and called by the "open" method like:

```
this.open(){
  // ... panel opening stuff
  this.onOpen.apply();
}
```

I'm looking for a way to add/remove methods from the callback. I thought of setting the callback methods as an array, but that would require wrapping each method with a function (or else JS would complain if the method is not yet set (e.g. one of the callback methods is to close a panel that was not yet created)).

Comment: could you pass in a list of panels to `this.open()` then pass that on in the `.apply()` call, then loop over that list in `onOpen`, thus only closing those panels specified in the list?

Comment: Might work for this specific case, but there'll be other cases in which there'll be other widgets with other methods, like a modal, or a <video> event.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in a way like:

```
Page.menu = Widget.sidePanel({
  onOpenHandlers: [],
  onOpen: function(){
    console.log('menu is going to be open');
    for(var i = 0; i < this.onOpenHandlers.length; i++) {
      this.onOpenHandlers[i]();
    }
  }
});
```

And then you need to populate that handler list:

```
Page.menu.onOpenHandlers.push(Page.otherPanel.close);
Page.menu.onOpenHandlers.push(function() {
  console.log('yetAnother is being closed due to menu open');
  Page.yetAnother.close();
});
```

---

If you need to remove handlers, you may build more complex structure for handler list:

```
[
  {
    id: 'some_unique_handler_id',
    run: function() { /* some handler logic */ }
  },
  //...
]
```

It will require an additional call:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.onOpenHandlers.length; i++) {
  this.onOpenHandlers[i].run();
}
```

Then two methods should be implement (somewhere, on Page.utils or even globally):

```
function addHandler(list, id, run) {
  var found = list.find(function(item) { return item.id === id });
  if(found) { // just replace the callback
    found.run = run;
  }
  else {
    list.push({ id: id, run: run});
  }
}

function removeHandler(list, id) {
  var foundIndex = list.findIndex(function(item) { return item.id === id });
  if(foundIndex >= 0) {
    list.splice(foundIndex, 1);
  }
}
```

The usage is obvious:

```
addHandler(Page.menu.onOpenHandlers, "otherPanelId", Page.otherPanel.close);
addHandler(Page.menu.onOpenHandlers, "yetAnotherId", function() {
  console.log('yetAnother is being closed due to menu open');
  Page.yetAnother.close();
});

removeHandler(Page.menu.onOpenHandlers, "otherPanelId");
```

Sorry for `find` and `findIndex`! just to make this graft a bit simpler.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the reply! It gave me an idea that might work. I'm thinking about creating a global callback manager with the object model you suggested, as I already have a similar implementation for window/document events. I guess a global event manager would justify a more complex concept like this and I could also find a way to manipulate execution order, that's been a long time itch. I'm trying to find a lib/framework that does it, I can't be the only one with this issue.